# I am getting 'p-calendar' is not a known element error even after importing CalendarModule and adding it to imports in AppModule

Tags: angular, primeng

I am getting 'p-calendar' is not a known element error even after importing CalendarModule and adding it to imports in AppModule

Actual error message in browser console

`Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'p-calendar'.
1. If 'p-calendar' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-calendar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.`

```
Dependencies list in my package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that the two way binding requires FormsModule

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

also add it to @NgModule imports

Answer (score 0):

Did you also import the `Commonmodule`? It contains `ngModel`